# How to include negation in this JQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML fragment.

```
<div class="diagram-frame">
    <div class="diagram">
        <span class="diagram-name">Drawing Objects</span>
        <svg>...lots of child elements...</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="diagram-name">
        <a class="idlink" title="Drawing Objects (data models)" href="...">NA - Drawing Objects</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, I use this jQuery selector to detect what has been clicked on:

```
jClicked.add(jClicked.parents()).is('div.diagram-frame')
```

`jClicked` is jQuery object containing the clicked element.

But I need to exclude clicks on the `diagram-name` div. How can I add negation using the `.not('div.diagram-name')` function call?

Comment: And what's `jClicked`, where was that defined?

Answer (score 1):

Since `.is()` matches a css selector, why not use the css `:not()` pseudo, and do all in one command?

```
jClicked.add(jClicked.parents()).is('div.diagram-frame:not(.diagram-name)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
jClicked.add(jClicked.parents())
  .not(jClicked.$('div.diagram-name'))
  .is('div.diagram-frame')
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, Not certain about `jClicked` object ?

Try

```
$(function() {
    var jClicked = [];
    $(".diagram-frame").on("click", function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).parent().is("div.diagram-name")) {
        jClicked.push(e.target);
          console.log($(jClicked));
          alert(jClicked.length);
      }
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    var jClicked = [];
    $(".diagram-frame").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(e.target).parent().is("div.diagram-name")) {
        jClicked.push(e.target);
          console.log($(jClicked));
          alert(jClicked.length);
      }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="diagram-frame">
    <div class="diagram">
        <span class="diagram-name">Drawing Objects</span>
        <svg>...lots of child elements...</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="diagram-name">
        <a class="idlink" title="Drawing Objects (data models)" href="...">NA - Drawing Objects</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/2myjbuhL/